# How do I go back to the last named route with a given name in Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, html5-history

Lets say I have 5 named routes, Index, News, TaggedNews, NewsItem, TaggedNewsItem

- To change between various routes I call router.push and it is working properly
- When I am at the NewsItem or TaggedNewsItem I want to go back to the last non item url, how do I do that
- Take an example history stack like this
  Index
  News
  News
  TaggedNews
  TaggedNewsItem
  TaggedNewsItem
- when I lclick a button I want to go from the last TaggedNewsItem by N steps where N will take me to the last named route TaggedNews or News or Index whichever comes first
- how do I do this using Vue Router
- It gives the option go(N) where N is the number of steps, problem is I need to find N to see where the last Index or News or TaggedNews item is present

Comment: You can determine the number of pages in the history stack by looking at the value of the length(N) property: `window.history.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the vue router saves the history stack. You would need to save it yourself.

You can use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to keep track of the history stack and calculate the last different route path, and have it available everywhere you need.

An implementation could be something like:

> history.js

```js
const history = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        stack: [],
    },
    mutations: {
        PUSH_STACK(state, routeName) => state.stack.push(routeName),
    },
    actions: {
        pushStack({ commit }, routeName) => commit('PUSH_STACK', routeName),
    },
    getters: {
        lastDiff(state) {
            const reversed = state.stack.slice().reverse();
            const diff = reversed.findIndex(route => route !== reversed[0]);
            return -1 * diff;
        }
    }
}
export default { history }
```

> store.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { history } from './history';

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        history
    }
})
export default { store }
```

Include it in your `main.js` file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { store } from './store';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store
});
```

In your router file, you can add a [global after hook](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks) to push the path name to the store like this:

```js
import { store } from './store';

const router = // router config

router.afterEach((to) => store.dispatch('history/pushStack', to.name));
```

And in your components you can use it like this:

```js
const backN = this.$store.getters['history/lastDiff'];
this.$router.go(backN);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this works with router replace